# How to only show hover on div with same class name, but only on current div

Tags: jquery

So I am trying to display a hidden div onto an existing div, but only have the div that mouse is over be shown. I have a jsfiddle with it showing the error. On hover, it shows all the divs unhidden, but I only want the current div to be visible, and not all of them.

style:

```
  background-color: blue;
  color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.productHover{
      position: absolute;
      top: 20px;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      display: none;
      color: white;
}
```

HTML:

```
Apple
  <div class="productHover">
    0.1%
  </div>
</div>

<div class="product">
Apple2
  <div class="productHover">
    0.2%
  </div>
</div>

<div class="product">
Apple3
  <div class="productHover">
    0.3%
  </div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
    function() {
        $('.productHover').show();
    }, function() {
        $('.productHover').hide();
    }
 );
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/spaLo6zf/12/

The divs have the same class name, I am trying to only show one productHover at a time, and now all at same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your jQuery to:

```js
$('.product').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).find('.productHover').show();
  },
  function() {
    $(this).find('.productHover').hide();
  }
);
```

```css
.product {
  background-color: blue;
  color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.productHover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product">
  Apple
  <div class="productHover">
    0.1%
  </div>
</div>

<div class="product">
  Apple2
  <div class="productHover">
    0.2%
  </div>
</div>

<div class="product">
  Apple3
  <div class="productHover">
    0.3%
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. I thought I tried this or something similar but I think my syntax was a bit off. Cheers.